# Compounding Rate using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Hey so I'm having trouble figuring out how to calculate the compounding rate for a zero coupon bond in excel.

The question is: An item starts at X 3 years later it has a value of 103.09%, and at the end of the 5th year it has a value of 105.06%. What is the quarterly compounding rate 3 years forward. I'm trying to implement this in excel.

I've tried using the RATE function in excel however I'm missing a lot of the necessary information to use the function. Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: How to do financial calculations is off-topic, but how to implement a formula in Excel would be on-topic.  So to strip away the financial terms, you're talking about something with a starting value of X.  Three years later it will have a value of 103.09% of X, and at the end of the 5th year, the value will be 105.06% of X?  In the last two years, 103.09% of X increases to 105.06% of X, or a 1.911% increase (105.06%/103.09%).  So you want to convert that to a quarterly compounded rate that yields 101.911% in two years  (i.e., compounded 8 times)?  That would be 1.01911^(1/8)-1.  (cont'd)

Comment: There might be a way to do that with built-in functions, or you could just use Excel to do the calculation.

Comment: So I can do it on paper, however I don't know how to get excel to do the calculation for me. And I'll strip away the financial terms in an edit.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow what you are saying. I apologize if I sounded rude though.

Answer (score 2):

To use the RATE function, you can use the following:

```
nper = 8 //This is the number of periods for 2 years
Pmt = 0 //There are no payments being made till the end of the number of periods
Pv = 103.09//This is used to represent 103.09% of X
Fv = -105.06 //This is used to represent 105.06% of X
Type = 0 //Payment is at the end of the period
```

or you can do

```
=POWER(1.0506/1.0309,1/8) - 1
```

Comment: I thought it addresses the question by giving the inputs to the RATE function in Excel, that is what I thought the OP was looking for, isn't it?

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for the clarification. I'll update the answer. I think the second part of the answer will reduce to what you mentioned in your comment.